# VBA Matrix Print separate columns

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, printing

I've generated a matrix with x amount of rows and 2 columns. So Matrix(1 to x, 1 to 2)
As my Matrix has two columns, is it possible to print them (Without looping) to two different places.
For example: I want the column 1 of the Matrix to go on Sheet1 column A and column 2 of the Matrix to go to go on Sheet1 column C.

How do i do that? I only know how to print the entire Matrix out and can't seem to find a way to just print a part of it to a sheet. Below is what i have so far.

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine).Resize(UBound(Matrix,1), UBound(Matrix,2)).Value = Matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you don't want to resize your columns, just the rows. And then you can use `Application.Index` to return a single column of your array. Maybe the below could help you out:

---

**<sub>Sample Data:</sub>**

Imagine the following sample 2d-Matrix in `A1:B3`:

[image]

---

**<sub>Sample Code:</sub>**

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change to whichever sheets CodeName you working with

    'Get a 2D-array for testing
    arr = .Range("A1:B3")

    'Print the first column
    .Cells(1, 4).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Index(arr, 0, 1)

    'Print the 2nd column
    .Cells(1, 6).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Index(arr, 0, 2)

    'Print the nth column, change "n" to whichever column of your array.
    '.Cells(1, 4).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Index(arr, 0, n)

End With

End Sub
```

---

**<sub>Sample Result:</sub>**

[image]